# Java Generic interface with List<T> not accepting object type

Tags: java, generics, interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a system as follows:

`DtoMapper`: This is an interface which defines a contract any third party mappers should return objects as

```
    public interface DtoMapper<T> {

    /**
     * Converts list of T into FooResponse
     * @param List of T
     * @return FooResponse
     */
    FooResponse convertToFooResponse(final List<T> rewards);
```

`FooMapper`: implements `DtoMapper` passing a List of `Bar` as method argument, however the compiler does not like my override of the method implementation and is wanting the second implementation (bottom).

```
public final class FooMapper implements DtoMapper {


    @Override
    FooResponse convertToFooResponse(final List<Bar> listOfBars) {
        ... Logic
    }

     @Override
    public convertToFooResponse(final List listOfBars) {
        ... I dont want this
    }
```

How can I make my interface work with this requirement, so that in future another implementation of say `public convertToFooResponse(final list<Snafu> listOfSnafus);` ?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `FooMapper`?

Comment: Updated the class declaration for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitely implement `DtoMapper<Bar>` instead of `DtoMapper`.

Example:

```
public interface DtoMapper<T> {

    /**
    * Converts list of T into FooResponse
    * @param List of T
    * @return FooResponse
    */
    FooResponse convertToFooResponse(final List<T> rewards);
}

public class FooMapperImplementation implements DtoMapper<Bar> {
    @Override
    public FooResponse convertToFooResponse(List<Bar> rewards) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the generic specification when implementing the class:

```
public final class FooMapper implements DtoMapper<Bar> {
// Here -----------------------------------------^

    @Override
    FooResponse convertToFooResponse(final List<Bar> listOfBars) {
        ... Logic
    }
```

Comment: This answer is not adding anything new not provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39389316/6783451 which was posted before yours.

Comment: If think @JoseIgnacioAcinPozo is right. And he also added more information.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parameterized type

```
class FooResponse{}
class First{}
class Second{}

public interface DtoMapper<T> {
    FooResponse convertToFooResponse(final List<T> rewards);    
}

class FirstMapper implements DtoMapper<First> {
    @Override
    public FooResponse convertToFooResponse(List<First> list) {
        return null;
    }
}

class SecondMapper implements DtoMapper<Second> {
    @Override
    public FooResponse convertToFooResponse(List<Second> list) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the method, you can create a new list with interface type.

```
List<InterfaceType> listWithInterfaceType = new ArrayList<>(listWithObjectType);
```